# "no module named torch". But installed pytorch 1.3.0 with conda in Ubuntu 18.04.02 Server Edition

Tags: python-3.x, module, pytorch, conda, ubuntu-18.04

installed pytorch with conda :

```
(base) (3.8.0/envs/my_virtual_env-3.8.0) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch/examples$ conda install  
pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I updated conda:

```
(base) (3.8.0/envs/my_virtual_env-3.8.0) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch/examples$ conda update 
conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Installed mkl=2019 :

```
(base) (3.8.0/envs/my_virtual_env-3.8.0) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch/examples$ conda install  
mkl=2019
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(base) (3.8.0/envs/my_virtual_env-3.8.0) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch/examples$ conda list | grep 
torch
cpuonly                   1.0                           0    pytorch
facenet-pytorch           0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   1.3.0               py3.7_cpu_0  [cpuonly]  pytorch
torchfile                 0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.4.1                  py37_cpu  [cpuonly]  pytorch
```

But it still says "no module torch" :

```
(base) (3.8.0/envs/my_virtual_env-3.8.0) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch/examples$ python3
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 30 2019, 16:20:23) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>>
```

I discovered that the problem appears only with python 3.8.0 version

```
(base) marco@pc:~/facenet_pytorch$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>>
```

Ubuntu 18.04.02 Server Edition

Or, may be, it's just a matter of python environments, as you said.
But I do not understand why just activating conda environment, with "conda activate", it doesn't work

Marco

Comment: I noticed in your first attempt (using Python 3.8.0) that it's not showing the Anaconda log `[GCC 7.X.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux`. Just making sure, you can verify with `which python3` if it wasn't pointing to the system's path, instead of Anaconda's. By the way, it seems there isn't a binary for 3.8.0 in [Anaconda yet](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a Conda environment using:

```
conda create -n pytorch_env python=3 ( you can create with any python version )
```

Activate the environment using:

```
conda activate pytorch_env
```

Now install PyTorch using:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch
```

Go to python shell and import using the command:

```
import torch
```

Comment: The `conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch` command crashes. I get "The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch-cpu"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your kind answers.
I solved the problem
- first, "downgrading" python from 3.8.0 to 3.7.3 because I checked in PyTorch's chat environment that PyTorch is not yet compatible with python 3.8.0
- and then, after removing everything already installed, installing the latest version of PyTorch via cunda, as you kindly explained

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch can be installed via pip and conda. For that, you need to create a separate conda environment. Thus, it will not corrupt the base environment.
Steps to create a new conda environment as follows:

```
conda create -n conda_pytorch python=3.6
source activate conda_pytorch
```

Follow the below command to install pytorch via pip:

```
pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Pytorch installation via conda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Verify the pytorch installation in the python shell using:

```
import torch
```